# Client-Server Data Synchronisation Strategies [Java]

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, synchronization

I have an app that communicates with a Rest WebService.  We want implement a strategy in which the App will first ask for the first X number of items, and once it used them all, will ask for the next X. Well my question is about the best practice/model/algorithm to implement in the server to solve this specification.

Our approach A

- The server knows it has Z items in total (say 100)
- Every time the App asks for new items it will inform the server how many time it did before. Something like URL/givemedata/1 or URL/givemedata/6 . In the first request the server will send the first 10 items on db, and in the seconde example the server will send items from 50 to 60.

**Problem**: 
        What if we insert new data on the server? What if we delete data from the server? If at the time the 1st request was made the server had 100 items, it would send the first 10 items to the app. But if at the time of the 2nd request the server had 300 items and we kept the same logic (10% of the total) the server would return to the app items from 30 to 60. Not only we wouldn't be sending 20 items, we could be sending repeated items in the future if we deleted some from the server.

Our approach B

- Save every item we send to each client.

**Problem**: This is, what I like to call, the lazy choice. Because its easy to save what we have sent to each client and then just exclude from future requests the ones we have already sent but in terms of performance this could be big problem (just imagine if we had 10000 items and 20000 clients.)

Now, is there a pattern or best known practice to approach an issue like this?

Comment: One approach is just show chunk of data _actual at the moment server received client request_. This way client view may become "slightly inconsistent", but you can send to client special flag "There was a change since your last request, consider re-requesting data you requested before". It depends on client needs, but it may be that client won't need to re-request often.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the following idea:

a) The server knows it has Z items in total (say 100) *at the moment the client called it for the first time*. This is handled by saving the server-side timestamp of the call in an hashtable, with the client ID as key.

b) Every time the App asks for new items it will get back a set of *N* (let say 10) items as a set/array/whatever - plus a number informing the client of how many items have not been returned yet.

Example: (100 items, 10 every time)

- Client #34 calls Server {it's 20141023-10:04:34 for the server)
- Server saves #34,20141023-10:04:34 in its internal state structures.
- Server returns: ((ax,bc,rr,tt,yd,ty,ae,t4,t2,a2), 90) i.e. a set of
  10 elements, and the notification that another 90 are waiting.
- Client #34 calls Server (again {it's 20141023-10:05:11 for the
  server)) Server returns ((vx,gf,gg,yu,td,fr,we,aq,ee,lp), 80) i.e. a
  set of 10 elements, and the notification that another 80 are waiting.
- Someone creates item "u7" on Server, at time {it's 20141023-10:05:12
  for the server)
- Client #34 calls Server (again {it's 20141023-10:05:58 for the
  server)) Server returns:    ((zx,gk,ig,tg,ed,rz,wt,a5,1e,wj), 71)
  i.e. a set of 10 elements, and     the notification that another 71
  are waiting... because it knows that    a new item was created since
  the original request had been received.

Finally, when the Server returns the last item, so:

- Client #34 calls Server (this is the 11th call because some other stuff has been created during the conversation  {it's 20141023-10:09:25 for the server))
- Server returns: ((zq,g1,i3,t7,e7,r9,sa,ax,1x,k6), 0) and removes #34 from its tables.

As long as you keep track of when a given item has been created on the Server (which is probably something you do already for other reasons) you can always know if the client first call included or not a given item in the result set.
Same applies to deleting items, too, if this makes sense to you.

The trick is to keep track of what point in time you started serve the first request, and from then on you can easily see if the set has been changed just by confronting the timestamp with creation/deletion timestamps.
You can of course decide that you do now want to inform the client of the creation of new items (so it will get a result consistent to the server status at a specific point in time).
By making the response dataset a bit more complicated you can also alert the client that one or more of the objects it has on "its side" have been deleted, if this makes sense in your case.

---

**Caveat:**

*While this should provide a viable solution for the problem as stated, keep in mind that the actual implementation must take in account a problem due to ordering. You have to decide if this has to be managed or not, depending on your situation: if it is indeed a problem, the returnset structure (and the Client interpretation) will become more complex.*

The problem is the following: in most cases the resultset (albeit "paginated") will have some inherent ordering: it could be "by price, ascending" or anything else, depending on the context. If this is indeed the case, you have now a whole new problem to deal with:

- In case of creation of a new object during the Client/Server conversation, you are not guaranteed that your new object shouldn't be part of the partial answers you already delivered to the client (unless your "ordering criteria" was something like "creation timestamp").
- This is even worse in case of deletions that might happen during the Client/Server exchange, because if an object that was already delivered to the client is deleted, the notification will be even more complex to deal with.

Unless it is really a strict requirement I'd opt for the API to return a consistent snapshot according to the timestamp of the first call.

Comment: Nice approach . With that we assure we store minimal data regarding all the clients , and we guarantee new items will always be given to the client .  I would add a thing. The server needs to know which set to send to the client. Either the client will inform the server (like I stated in the question , something like /givemeitems/N ) or the server needs to have a state in which it knows for each client, which Nth set to send.  Thank you

Comment: @NokusFerreira - yes, of course the specifics of the dialogue may have much more details, I just wanted to give a simple way to make sure to get over the "what if someone added/changed/deleted the resultset while the client was consuming it?" problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simple strategy:

**Step 1** Retrieve a list of items to update

**Step 2** Transmit that list to the client

**Step 3** Split the requests into chunks (1000 entries per page) and query page by page

**Step 4** Set a timestamp on the entries on the client, e.g. *justupdated* = `now()`

**Step 5** Retrieve a list of items to update and substract all entries just updated

**Step 6** Until there is an empty set, repeat from **Step 3**

**Step 7** When the delta is 0. Your update is done.

*Alternatively:*

**Step 1** evaluate all outdated entries on the client (older than *x*)

**Step 2** query pagewise updates for all outdated entries from the client and set the update-timestamp

**Step 3** ask server for updates

**Step 4** query pagewise and set the update-timestamp on the clientside

**Step 5** ask server for updates

**Step 6** calculate the delta with already updated entires. Until delta =0 retrieve data pagewise and set timestamp. and repeat **Step 5**

Answer (score 0):

What if you saved a list containing hashed values of all items received on the client, and send it to the server via the request each time?

1. The server would save a hash for each item in a list (or DB, whatever you use), and so when it receives a request, it compares the items it has to the received list of hashed items it got from the client.
2. The server only sends the first 10 items that were not in the list it got from the client (meaning the client never saw them until now).
3. Every time the server deletes items (or in predetermined intervals), it will notify every client that sends a request that those items were deleted (also via a list of hashes), and so the client can empty its list as well thus avoiding a bloated list.

Comment: I understand your point but that's the kind of thing we are trying to avoid . Imagine that we have to send not 100 items, but 1000 items each time. Regardless the size of these objects, i don't think it is efficient or recommendable to send in the client request that amount of data and make the server, for each request , compare what it receives with what it has. @p.marino ideia achieves the same objective plus it doesn't overload requests and performance. Thank you